# Do golf balls fly faster than the swing speed of the club? Or are they equal? If not, how do golf balls fly faster than speed of club?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, everyday-life, collision

How is it possible that golf balls or for that matter baseballs or any such hit object can travel faster than the speed of the thing used to hit them?

Comment: The ball "bounces" off the face of the club.

Comment: @river chess if the bat used stops at the time of impact then conserving the momentum, the ball will fly at a greater speed.

Comment: @Ankit I think it is too unrealistic to assume that the bat stops at the time of impact.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps a useful way of thinking of the problem is as an elastic collision of two objects of very unequal mass.  In this kind of collision, the very light mass object (the golf ball) moves away with twice the speed of the very massive object that hit it (the golf club).

Following http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/elacol2.html, for a head-on elastic collision of a mass $m_1$ moving at velocity $v_1$ onto a mass $m_2$ at rest, the resultant velocity of $m_2$ is $$v_2'=\frac{2m_1}{m_1+m_2}v_1,$$ which, as promised, for $m_1\gg m_2$ yields $v_2'\approx 2v_1$.

Answer (score -1):

I would assume conservation of momentum applies, where (mass x velocity) of the golf club equals (mass x velocity) of the golf ball, and since the ball's mass is smaller than the club's, it travels faster than the club is moving.

Comment: Why would momentum of golf ball be equal to momentum of club? Shouldnt conservation of momentum mean, total momentum of ball + club before  impact = total momentum of ball + club after impact ?

Comment: I would agree... Plus, wouldn't the golf club have angular momentum?

Comment: yes you're right, I was assuming the club stops immediately after impact. Either way, the club loses some momentum to the ball which makes it go faster than the club itself, despite the club still having its own velocity.

Comment: @CharlesTucker3 yes. Mind you, after being hit the golf ball also has a *lot* of angular momentum, in its very required backspin.